# Parse Cloud Code on Heroku User Query

Tags: heroku, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to access properties located on the User object for the current user in a cloud code function. The current user is passed to the cloud code function and available at `request.user`. The Cloud Code is deployed to Heroku using `parse-cloud-express`.

When the request first arrives, it does not contain the user data other than the `id`.

So I tried performing a fetch to get the latest data:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("functionName", function (request, response) {
  request.user.fetch().then(function (user) {
    console.log(util.inspect(user));
  });
});
```

But it outputs the same data and does not seem to include the User object's properties.

```
2015-12-15T01:19:08.830880+00:00 app[web.1]: { _objCount: 1, className: '_User', id: 'dKqZMSRgDc' }
```

I also tried performing a query on the user id, but receive the same result.

```
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQuery.get(request.user.id).then(function (user) {
  console.log(util.inspect(user));
});
```

How do I get the properties of the User object?

Comment: So just refer to here:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286919/parse-cloud-code-retrieving-a-user-with-objectid?noredirect=1&lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286919/parse-cloud-code-retrieving-a-user-with-objectid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with getting data for the User object, but the way I was logging it. It seems that the data is not available from the object itself, so the output from `util.inspect` was correct, but does not include any properties. (I'm guessing the internals of the Parse framework manages this in another way.)

I replaced with `console.log(user.toJSON())` and can now see the expected data for the user.