# Parse Cloud Code User Query Error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am trying to query the user class to find a user whose `objectId` I pass from my app to Cloud Code. I keep getting this error when I try to deploy my code to Parse:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL in main.js:4

Can someone let me know what I am doing wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.define("followerCount", function(request, response) {
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    userQuery.equalTo(“objectId”, request.params.objectId);
    var query = new Parse.Query("Friends");
    query.equalTo("toUser", userQuery);
    query.count({
        success: function(count) {
            response.success(count);
        },
        error: function() {
            response.error("count failed");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Cloud Code retrieving a user with objectId](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286919/parse-cloud-code-retrieving-a-user-with-objectid)

Comment: Please refer to this:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286919/parse-cloud-code-retrieving-a-user-with-objectid?noredirect=1&lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26286919/parse-cloud-code-retrieving-a-user-with-objectid?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong kind of quotes here: `“objectId”`.

Replace them with the correct quotes: `"objectId"`

Comment: the correct quotes did allow it to deploy to Parse. Thank you! But I get an error when it tries to run the cloud code response. Any suggestions?

Comment: this is the error i received.   [Error]: undefined (Code: 141, Version: 1.11.0)

Comment: @TreyR [A quick Googling](http://parse.com/docs/dotnet/api/html/T_Parse_ParseException_ErrorCode.htm) shows that it means a script failed. I've never used Parse so I couldn't tell you why.